# Spawning multiple threads for socket testing C#

Tags: c#, sockets, stress-testing

I have a multithreaded Server which is running on TCP Sockets.

I have written this method to test for multiple threads

```
TcpClient[] ClientArray = new TcpClient[10000];
for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
     ClientArray[i] = new TcpClient();
     // connect is my connect method to connect to the server
     ClientArray[i].connect() 
}
```

Is this method correct or would there be a better method to test for simultaneous connections

Comment: Assuming the above is your client side test code, you appear to be creating 10,000 connections one after another (serially).  It depends on how your server handles those connections as to what is getting tested.  It would certainly show that the server can handle 10,000 connections.  You might look at Parallel.For http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460713.aspx

Comment: It looks like you're actually testing the `TcpClient` or `TcpListener` here. I wouldn't write tests for this. I would say it's enough to test your server logic with maybe two concurrent connection attempts. That should prove that your communication is working well and nothing is blocked.